# How do I set up docker containers to communicate on private network?

Tags: linux-networking, docker

I have a small cluster at rackspace with a private network in the range 192.168.3.0/24. I would like my worker services to talk to each other using this network but can't figure out how to get docker to allow that.

My ideal configuration would be a single public-facing container that proxies the connections to a worker that can then talk to various services within the private network to do its job.

```
eth0 -> load balancer --> 192.168.3.3:80 --> 192.168.3.5:1234 (db)
                      \-> 192.168.3.4:80 /
                       \> 192.168.3.5:80/
```

If all the workers were on the same machine I could accomplish this with `docker run --link ...` but since they're on different machines, that won't work.

The workers in the above example are started with a command similar to this:

```
docker run -d -p $PRIVATE_IPV4:80:80 myworker
```

and the database started like this:

```
docker run -d -p $PRIVATE_IPV4:1234:1234 mydb
```

From the **host** I can talk to each of the containers just fine but each container cannot route to any other container. I.E. `curl http://192.168.3.4` works from the host, but not from a container running on the host.

The load balancer in this case is nginx started like this:

```
docker run -d -p $PUBLIC_IPV4:80:80 nginx
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream app {
  server 192.168.3.3:80;
  server 192.168.3.4:80;
  server 192.168.3.5:80;
}
...
```

This seems like it would be a pretty standard configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/829682/how-do-i-add-a-computer-to-an-internal-docker-network/831005#831005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try implementing your architecture in a container manager like Kubernetes on top of CoreOS. There are many guides out there. This is a walk-through from a presentation at DockerCon https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/11427/136165 about Container Cluster Management.

Comment: I decided to use https://github.com/coreos/flannel which is a component written by the coreos team to allow Kubernetes to work on core-os. https://github.com/metral/corekube/blob/master/README.md gives a good explanation of why I was running into issues and how flanneld solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Docker by itself does not provide container networking facilities. [Weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave) is one of the easiest to use overlay SDN solutions. It works in any cloud and even across multiple clouds.

I should disclaim, I am one of Weave engineering team.